# Post Ajax request from a PHP loop

Tags: php, jquery

I have a simple do / while loop and I want to send via post to a side php script some info to do a bunch of thinks. In this case  creates an txt file by appending the results (this php scripts works just fine).
I tried to wrap it is a form but I am getting only one record

I want to do whatever needs do be done via AJAX (to a separate file/script) and NOT inside the main loop

Any Ideas....

***JS***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = $("#myForm").serialize();
    $.post('MY_PHP_SCRIPT.php', data,function(retData){
      });
});
```

***PHP / HTML***

```
<?php do ?>
    <form id='myForm'>
    <input name="list_id" type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $row_Recipients['list_id']; ?>" />
    <input name="reg_id" type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $row_Recipients['reg_id']; ?>" />
    </form>
} while ($row_Recipients = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recipients)); ?>
```

***MY_PHP_SCRIPT***  (Just for testing purposes)

```
<?php 
$txt = $_POST['reg_id'].' '.$_POST['list_id'] ;
 $myfile = file_put_contents('logs.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

Comment: Your trick is going to be that the AJAX requests which you attempt to send in your loop will be processed *asynchronously.*  You probably need to redesign your logic so that it sends the next AJAX request when it has determined that the preceding one completed successfully.

Comment: Actually the issue is most likely the duplicate form ids being generated by the php/html.  The javascript lookup by `#myForm` is only going to find the first one, **because ids are expected to be unique**

Comment: @Taplar so now the IDs looks like "myForm_1", "myForm_2",..."myForm_n" and var now is var data = ($(this).attr("id")).serialize(); but still not luck. BTW j script is not my best